# Oracle Stored Procedure Execution in Hibernate Query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, stored-procedures

I have a procedure like this :

```
create or replace PROCEDURE Greeting1 IS sqlstmt varchar2(400);
BEGIN
   sqlstmt:= 'select * from Object_set';
   EXECUTE immediate sqlstmt;
END;
```

I want to execute it in java code like this:

```
List<String> result = null;
Query query = getEm().unwrap(Session.class).createSQLQuery("CALL Greeting1()");
    if(query.list() != null) {
         result = query.list();
    }
return result;
```

But it gives error while getting query.list(). Actually it returns null in Query Objects.
How should I get the proper result list. Please suggest me.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really know stored procedure with Oracle but JPA set an interface to execute stored procedure, you should read this: [Calling Stored procedure with Hibernate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#sql-sp).

This take care of the case where you use `IN`, `OUT` and `IN OUT` parameters, otherwise for stored function you will have to use jdbc API instead.

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's not possible to use the `query.list();` method
What I usually do when I need to inovke stored procedure in a hibernate+spring environment is something like this:

```
//sessionFactory objext is autowired in this DAO
Session hibSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
hibSession.doWork(new Work()
{
    @Override
    public void execute(Connection sqlConnection) throws SQLException
    {
        //Here I call the stored procedure and valorize my java POJOS if needed
    }
});
```

I hope it's useful

Angelo